# How to Retrieve Data and display the user name from Firebase When pushed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to Retrieve and display the user name with this code but Every node have a unique Id.

```
Firebase MainFirebase;
private Button btnProfile;
private Button btnLibrary;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProfile);
    btnLibrary = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLibrary);
    final TextView FullName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVFullName);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext());

    MainFirebase = new Firebase("https://avastus-mcphil.firebaseio.com/Name");

    MainFirebase.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String myChildText = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            FullName.setText(myChildText);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            FullName.setText("Error Found!");

        }
    });
```

What is the best way to retrieve the pushed data?

this is what my Database look like:

> -L4ampm6pwMeWA9X7A20
>
> Email: "mcphil@haha.com"
>
> Name: "Avastus"

Comment: It looks like you're using an extremely old version of Firebase Realtime Database.  I strongly suggest updating to the latest.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Im using it now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      String keys=datas.getKey(); 
      String displayname=datas.child("Name").getValue().toString();

     }
}

 @Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
  }
});
```

Assuming the push id is under the root node.

Added retrieving name assuming the name in your database is `Name`.

Comment: @AvastusLearn added display name

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Answer, but i got an error, still not displaying the name on device

Comment: add this `FullName.setText(displayname);`. You need to have `Name` in your databse with capital `N`. If you do not have that then its probably lowercase `n`? so `child("name")` @AvastusLearn